# Select List Generated using JSON and jQuery appends empty options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a field that represents a zip code of a user. When the user leaves that text box, an AJAX request is sent to the server to receive cities that may be associated with that zip code.

I am trying to use the JSON received from that request to populate a select list to replace the text box that is currently assumed for city (if one city is returned, I just change the value of the text box).

For example, a user puts in 20910 as their zip code and it returns Silver Spring. I replace the textbox for city with Silver Spring. Another user puts in 84107 as their zip code and it replaces the textbox with a select list of Murray, Salt Lake City.

It receives the JSON just fine, but I am not sure if I am doing something wrong in my JavaScript. When the select is rendered, it gives blank fields after each value.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$('#AddressData_ZipCode').blur(function() {
            var zip = $('#AddressData_ZipCode').val();
            var pattern = /^\d{5}([\-]\d{4})?$/;
            if (zipCode.length > 0 && pattern.test(zip)) {
                $.getJSON("/GeneralInfo/GetCitiesInZip", { zipCode: zip }, function(data) {
                    if (data.length > 1) {
                        var citiesComboBuilder = "<select id='AddressData_City'>";
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            citiesComboBuilder += "<option value='" + data[i] + "'>" + data[i] + "<option/>";
                        }
                        citiesComboBuilder += "</select>";
                        $('#AddressData_City').replaceWith(citiesComboBuilder);
                    }
                    else
                        $('#AddressData_City').val(data);
                });
            }
        });
```

This is the returned JSON:
    ["Murray","Salt Lake City"]

And this is the HTML that I receive after the function runs:

```
<select id="AddressData_City">
 <option value="Murray">Murray</option>
 <option/>
 <option value="Salt Lake City">Salt Lake City</option>
 <option/>
</select>
```

Any help would be great. Any suggestions to improve this code would be great also. Thanks.

Comment: Post your json that gets returned so we can see that.

Comment: added it to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
citiesComboBuilder += "<option value='" + data[i] + "'>" + data[i] + "<option/>";
```

Here is your solution:

```
citiesComboBuilder += "<option value='" + data[i] + "'>" + data[i] + "</option>";
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe I didn't catch that. Thanks.

Comment: You were probably looking too hard.

Comment: ahh beat me to it by seconds ;p

Answer (score 0):

The option tag is closed wrong in your JavaScript, you have `<option/>`. It looks like the browser is trying to correct it and failing.